# Shapes don't match google maps QGIS 2.18.7

Tags: qgis, maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin, google

I have some shapes (in EPSG:4326 wgs 84) that match with Openlayers ->google street maps only when I do enough zoom-in.

But When I zoom-out seems that my shapes move to the east.

What could be happening?

I think it might be something related to projection. But since I am newbie in GIS I dont know deeply qgis tools and configurations.

In picture below Black line should be matching with red line, than happens only if I zoom-in.

[image]

By the way, the more zoom-out, the more shapes move to east.

Comment: its not your data, its the google map layer that is shifting

Comment: Try using QuickMapServices plugins, this helped me

Comment: ... or check against an OpenStreetMap background.

Comment: Is the project CRS set to `EPSG:3857`?